# How to only put selected fields into mongo array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Got one agency table - each agency can have have several users
I want the users[] array but only with limited fields

This one works, but it put waaaay too much information into the users[] array...

```
    agencyTable.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {}
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    activityDate: 1
                }
            },              
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "users",
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "agency", 
                    as: "users"     
                }   
            },
            { $unwind: "$users" },
            { $match: { 'users.type': 'agent' } }, 
            {
                $group: {
                    "_id": "$_id",
                    "phone": { "$first": "$phone" },
                    "activityDate": { "$first": "$activityDate" },
                    "users": { "$push": "$users" }
                }
            },  
            {
                $project: {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "phone" : 1,
                    "activityDate" : 1,
                    "users" : 1
                    // "userID" : "$users._id",
                    // "userName" : "$users.name",
                    // "userPhone" : "$users.phone",
                }
            }]
```

I then try to uncomment the lower 3 lines, but then something strange happens....

```
vm.agencyRecord : [
    {
        "_id": "Mic Agency Ltd",
        "phone": "ZZZZ",
        "activityDate": 1521460192,
        "userID": [
            "michael@micagency.com",
            "nana@micagency.com",
            "gogo@micagency.com",
            "wollahsom@micagency.com",
            "sdfsdf@werwerwer.ccc",
            "werwer@ertert.dd"
        ],
        "userName": [
            "Michael Agent",
            "Nana Banana",
            "Gogo Banana",
            "Wollah Woldsom",
            "weqweqweqwe",
            "werwer"
        ],
        "userPhone": [
            "99 22 99 22 33",
            "111 222 999",
            "111 222 999",
            "234234234",
            "34234234234",
            "werwerwer"
        ]
    },
```

And of cause thats not what I want.  I wanna keep the same users array just with far fewer fields.

Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to limit the fields.

[`$$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) syntax to access the `usr` user variable to reference the element followed by fields mapping you wish to keep.

Something like

```
{
  "$project":{
    "_id":1,
    "phone":1,
    "activityDate":1,
    "users":{
      "$map":{
        "input":"$users",
        "as":"usr",
        "in":{
          "userID":"$$usr._id",
          "userName":"$$usr.name",
          "userPhone":"$$usr.phone"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can simplify your aggregation using `$addFields` stage instead of `$project` stage.

```
{
   "$addFields":{
      "users":{
        "$map":{
           "input":"$users",
           "as":"usr",
           "in":{
              "userID":"$$usr._id",
              "userName":"$$usr.name",
              "userPhone":"$$usr.phone"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Veeram to the rescue as usual :-)  Thanks once again.  (didnt know about $addFields, thanks for teaching something new)